# What is the goal of the OSI model?

Tags: network, osi

I'm currently learning about the OSI model, trying to understand exactly what it is and what is the purpose behind it.

The Wikipedia page says:

> The Open Systems Interconnection model (OSI model) is a conceptual model that characterises and standardises the communication functions of a telecommunication or computing system without regard to its underlying internal structure and technology. Its goal is the interoperability of diverse communication systems with standard communication protocols.

I fail to understand the intent of the sentence "its goal is the interoperability of diverse communication systems with standard communication protocols".

Was the OSI model developed as a guideline for someone who comes to design a new communication system? Is it just a description of existing systems?

Please clarify this for me.

Comment: Sometimes, I wish they'd stop teaching the OSI model.  I think it confuses more than it helps.

Comment: @RonTrunk I agree. It may be nice for new people to get a basic fundamental understanding of how things MIGHT work in an ideal world, but with the advent of SDN, virtual appliances, etc. the lines are so blurred it’s mostly irrelevant these days.

Comment: The major problem is that even many teachers don't really understand the exact relations. Going by a book, it's really hard to grasp. It's actually much easier if you start smaller and look at the big picture *much* later on.